# Find the eigenvalues the block matrix $M=\begin{bmatrix}A+2D & A \\ A & D \end{bmatrix}$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $A$ be any square matrix with eigenvalues $\lambda_1,\lambda_2,\cdots,\lambda_n$ and $D$ is a diagonal matrix with entries $d_1,d_2,\cdots,d_n$, then how can one find the
eigenvalues of the following block matrix?

$$M=\begin{bmatrix}A+2D & A \\ A & D \end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: Is there any relation between $A$ and $D$? For example, are the diagonal entries of $D$ the row sums of $A$?

Comment: yes of course because $A$ is adjacency matrix of graph and $D$ is degree matrix

Comment: Does the answer at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/54133/eigenvalues-of-certain-block-matrices?rq=1 help?

Comment: It is very much helpful